# RxJS countdown timer doesn't reach zero

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, countdowntimer

I have a `startCountdown()` function in my `angular` app that is basically a 2-minute countdown timer.

Problem is, it doesn't reach zero and stops at `0:01`.

`startCountdown()` function is as follows:

```
startCountdown(): void {
    const timerInterval$ = interval(1000); //1s
    const timer$ = timer(120000); //120s
    const times = 120;
    const countDown$ = timerInterval$.pipe(take(times));
    const sub = countDown$.subscribe((val) => {
      this.countdownTimer = secondsToTime(times - val);
    });
  }
```

And this is the `secondsToTime()` function:

```
secondsToTime(seconds: number): string {
  const minute: number = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  const second: number = seconds == 0 ? 0 : seconds % 60;

  if (second < 10) {
    return `${minute}:0${second}`;
  } else {
    return `${minute}:${second}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would consider using takewhile instead of take for your use case. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile

Comment: @alou I read the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well: the `interval(1000).pipe(take(120))` emit 120 values from 0 to 119

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the `this.countdownTimer = secondsToTime(times - val);` to `this.countdownTimer = secondsToTime(times - (val + 1));` and now it's fixed.